# AngularJS ngCloak not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a post category page that should show a message if there are no posts. It's showing the HTML when the page loads and then hiding it. ngCloak sounds like it should do the job but i'm not having any luck with it. Here's the HTML in my template file:

```
  <div ng-show="data.posts.length == 0" ng-cloak>
    <div class="no-posts">
      <h2>Coming Soon</h2>
      <p>Sorry there are posts here yet, check back soon.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the CSS i've added to my sass file. I also tried adding it directly into CSS on the page but it did not work:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

What am I missing? This should be so simple right?

**Edit: I also added this into the HTML head and it didn't work:**

```
<style type="text/css">
  [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: make sure this CSS should loaded at the start from head tag..

Comment: Hi, I also tried that and it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Ng-cloack directive works completely in another way than you expect it. It does not hide HTML, it does show it once template becomes compiled.
The reason is that template compilation in the browser takes some time upon which ugly template without data will be shown to user. To hide uncompiled template you need to add ng-cloak class (to make it invisible) and ng-cloack directive to show after template compilation.
The problem you describe here has another solution: you have to add **'ng-hide' class** to your element, and it will be hidden until expression for ng-show wont take 'true' value.

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
  angular.module('demo', [])
   .controller('DemoController', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
     var vm = this; 
  
     vm.isLoaded = true;
  }]);
angular.bootstrap(document, ['demo']);
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="DemoController as vm">
<div>Message below will appear in 3 seconds</div>
<div class="ng-hide" ng-show="vm.isLoaded">Data is loaded</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thank you, that explains why it wasn't working. So I tried this `ng-hide ng-show="data.posts.length == 0"` and got the same outcome. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add ng-hide as class or as attribute?

Comment: I have added a code snippet which demonstrates usage ng-hide class

Comment: Thank you. All I wanted was a message to show if there are no posts to loop through. This seems like an overly complicated way to do that. Is there no simple solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean? Your code is correct, all you need is just to add ng-hide class to div.

Comment: This is my code `<div class="ng-hide" ng-show="data.posts.length == 0">` I also tried adding a .ng-hide class into CSS with `display: none` but that didn't work either

Comment: I have changed it to `ng-if`and my code works, is this bad practice?

Comment: I mean as a snippet

Comment: ng-if is ok i think